# Best practices for inline SQL queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm working with an asp.net website that uses a lot of inline SQL queries... and I'm wondering if it is best to create the inline queries on the fly:

```
int i = 500;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(conn);
        ...
        com.CommandText = "select from table where column < @parameter";
        ...
    }
```

Or to have a class to hold all queries needed for the application. Something like this:

```
class SqlQueries
{
    private string query1 = 
          "select * from tblEmployees where EmployeeName = @EmployeeName";

    private string query2 = 
          "select * from tblVacation where EmployeeName = @EmployeeName";

    public string Query(string s) 
    { 
        string str = string.Empty;

            switch (s) 
            {
                case "query1":
                    str = query1; 
                    break; 
                case "query2":
                    str = query2; 
                    break;
            }     

    return str;    

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you decide to take the indirection approach number 2 then I would suggest creating a dictionary indexed by query names containing the SQL. You can then use a dictionary initializer to list all your queries in almost a table-like manner in your source code. Your current approach is verbose and susceptible to copy-paste errors (currently there is at least one that however will be discovered by the compiler). `new Dictionary<string, string> { { "query1", "select * ..." }, { "query2", "select * ..." } };`

Comment: Thank you everybody! Too bad I can't select multiple answers :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used a lot of ADO.NET queries in my day and I have always used the first method.  The second method is an interesting idea, but it might be cumbersome to edit those queries if you are at another place in the code that uses it.  It also makes it harder to see what a query is doing at a particular place in code.  Example:

```
string sql = "Update User set age = @age where UserId = @UserId";
```

tells a developer what is happening, while:

```
string sql = SqlQueries.Query("updateAge");
```

Leaves questions about what table/columns are being updated.  Also, with the first one, you know exactly what params need to be added.

If you are writing this query in several places that might change things

Answer (score 6):

It's not terrible to put the literal directly in the method, as long as you always call that same method every time you want to run that query.  However, if you are going to copy that string literal into multiple places in your code, then a constant is definitely preferred.  However, rather than taking a string as the argument for the Query method in your second example, it should take an enumeration value.

However, if you are using the second method you described, I would ask you why you don't just start using stored procedures instead?

Comment: @Steven Doggart - In my case, two reasons: there are too many ppl with admin rights to the db (who shouldn't have), and to keep the queries under souce control.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using stored procedures as a much better solution to your problem than hard coded in-line queries.  If you have to change the query at a later date, you don't have to rebuild your application, so bugs in your query can be fixed without needing to deploy the whole application.  The 2nd option you have there is a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.  It all looks so nice when you have one or two queries in it, but that begins to look a bit more ugly when you have tens or hundreds in there.   Your code looks like it's c#, so I would recommend checking out the Microsoft Enterprise Library,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx

You might need to download a different version depending on what version of the .NET  framework you are developing with.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to have "inline" sql as opposed to stored procedures (and I have done this for utility type applications that merely *interact* with a database, rather than *own* it), I would suggest putting your SQL into an [embedded resource file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292).  This will make your queries easier to maintain (although you will still need to re-compile your app to make changes).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK to have the queries "inline" as long as they aren't repeated in several places.  If that starts to happen, then you might want to start creating Query classes.

Answer (score 0):

In both the cases you are ultimately building/fetching `String` which you will pass to `CommandText`. So there would be no such difference. Only thing you need to consider in your case is how you would maintain the code or how will other people understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use inline SQL at least don't put it in the web page code because it will be painful when you make database changes to know what it affects. Putting all the queries in one classes might be a bit disorganized, but if you grouped them by functional classes (like manager classes for your business objects) it might be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are longer than a line or two, you should consider putting them in their own .sql file. Set the build action on the file to embedded resource, and access it with a call to GetManifestResourceStream(). That way, you're elevating your sql to the status of a proper language, with syntax highlighting, validation and intellisense (when you connect VS to your DB). Needless to say, this hugely facilitates maintenance.

If all this seems like a hassle, grab my VS extension, [QueryFirst](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb). Create your .sql files with the provided template and they will automatically be wired up for compilation. But you won't care because you'll just access the queries via the generated classes.

Sql is the only computer language I can think of that we accept to see chopped up in string literals. It ought to be a scandal.